# hide all except for current Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a container bound script with drawings that have functions assigned to them that change the current sheet to a predefined one.

Now i addition to switching sheets i'd also like to hide all sheets except the one sheet  im on / going to.


`if SwitchToSheet4 gets executed, hide all sheets except sheet4`

Heres my code but this doesn't work since it hides all sheets:

```
function hideAllSheets() {
  var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for(var i =0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    Logger.log(i);
    if(sheets[i].getName()!=null){
      sheets[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }
}
```

```
function SwitchToSheet1() {
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet1'), true);
  hideAllSheets();
};
function SwitchToSheet2() {
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet2'), true);
  hideAllSheets();
};
function SwitchToSheet3() {
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet3'), true);
  hideAllSheets();
};
function SwitchToSheet4() {
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet4'), true);
  hideAllSheets();
};
function SwitchToSheet5() {
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet5'), true);
  hideAllSheets();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Retrieve the active sheet using [Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivesheet).
- Filter out this sheet from the array of sheets, for example using the sheet id to identify it ([getSheetId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetid)).
- Hide all the other sheets.

#### Code snippet:

```
function hideAllSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const currentSheetId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.filter(s => s.getSheetId() != currentSheetId)
        .forEach(s => s.hideSheet());
}
```